# Can I restrict a graphics tablet/pen to work within a window?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-tablet

I have a cheap Huinon tablet. It works well enough.

But it represents the whole of the screen. While this means I can select menus etc, using it, I have no need to do that. I want to use the mouse for that

I'd lke to use the tablet only to draw within a window (e.g. a slide in powerpoint, the image in Lightroom) and have the area of the tablet cover only that window (so going to the top left of the tablet goes to the top left of the area I want to draw in, not the top left of the screen).

Is this possible?

Comment: I fear I don't understand your question correctly. What is your setup? Do you use your tablet connected to a computer? How? Extending your screen? What are your exact settings? ...

Comment: It's a graphics tablet, not a ipad or similar. so yes, connected to a computer, but not "extending the screen" as it doesn't have one.  It's one of these: https://www.huion.com/pen_tablets/K58/

Comment: Someone's voted to close as "too broad" which is odd. In what way could it be made less broad, it's pretty specific IMO

Comment: I'm not sure if the pen will work the same way a mouse does, but there's this: https://superuser.com/questions/918257/is-there-a-way-to-force-the-mouse-to-be-confined-to-an-arbitrary-window-in-windo